# I cannot use phpmyadmin on wamp, it stays loading forever

Tags: phpmyadmin, wamp

How have you been? I'm writing because I have been having problems trying to use PHPMyAdmin on Wamp. It stays loading forever, maybe it loads just once but then, If I click something or anything it stays loading, and sometimes it doesn't even load once, the browser just shows the loading symbol but never enters PHPMyAdmin. I tried several solutions and none of them worked, like deleting Google Chrome cookies, opening an incognito window, or deactivating the Google Chrome extensions. I also tested port 80 and I thought it looked fine, but even so, I did the taskkill/PID 7076 /F and when I did it the server crashed I had to restart it again and it came back but with the same problem. This is the port 80 test capture:

[port80](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BR7Do.png)

Comment: For future visitors, the issue might be with xdebug extension. Please deactivate and try again